# Django use view response in html file

Tags: python, django

I have a function in my views.py file that returns a list of files in a path and I want to use that list in a html file, so I call the view response in this way: `{% url 'files' %}`(I also tried with {{ }} notation but I got this error `Could not parse the remainder: '% url 'files' %' from '% url 'files' %'`) but i only get this `/files/` no the list I want, so how can I get the list ?

this is my views.py file :

```
def itemlist(request):
    files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('mypath'):
        for file in files:

            files.append(os.path.join(root,file))

    list_files = json.dumps(files) 
    return HttpResponse(list_files)
```

this is my urls.py file:

```
from almacen_folders.views import itemlist

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^django-admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^files/$',itemlist,name='files'),
]
```

in the html file i call the view like this `{% url 'files' %}`

Comment: Note that 'your_list_as_json' has not been created and will cause a NameError

Comment: sorry, was my mistake, i change the name of the variable

Comment: This code should work, I got a retuned list from the HttpResponse. Is it working now?

Comment: Yes, i mean, when i go to http://localhost:8000/files/ i works but when i do {% url 'files' %} i do not get a list in my html file

Comment: What do you mean when you do {% url 'files' %}? <a href="{% url 'files' %}">Link</a> will provide a link to that page. If you use that it should direct you to the page.

Comment: I need the image, <img src="{% url 'files' %}">, the list that contains a image path so i can show it in the page